# Django ForeignKeyRawIdWidget doesn't reduce queries when used in inline admin (stacked)

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a foreinkey relationship like this

```
class Product(models.Model):
    brochure = models.ForeignKey(MediaFile)
```

Because there are a lot of MediaFiles in my library I commonly use a `ForeignKeyRawIdWidget` to reduce the number of queries.

But apparently using a 'ForeignKeyRawIdWidget' on an inline model doesn't affect this. It still executes a lot of queries.

Does anyone know why this is?

Admin:

```
class ProductInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.Product
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'brochure':
            kwargs['widget'] = ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(db_field.rel)

        return super(ProductInline, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

vs

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'brochure':
            kwargs['widget'] = ForeignKeyRawIdWidget(db_field.rel)

        return super(ProductAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to overwrite the formfields. Django has an option for that:

```
class ProductInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = models.Product
    raw_id_fields = ['brochure']
    …
```

This works fine for my `StackedInline` or `TabularInline` models.